# ASP.NET Application suddenly restarts

Tags: asp.net

I have ASP.NET application on hosting provider for some tasks that I can't do on my own PC due to my slow connection.

Application uses multithreading, and has login screen at the start but the only user of application is me. Everything was fine until few days ago when my application started to restart itself after an hour of work or so,I Guess it doesn't lose session since I am still Loged on when restart happen,but my all variables and and controls are reverted to starting state.My application doesn't delete or modify any folders or files on server so that can't be a reason, and I am convinced this isn't caused by any error since I've inspected application few times for any kind of errors.

When this started to happen I noticed few cosmetic changes on my hosts Control Panel,and now Im unable to login trough Firefox to CP,because Login screen of Host CP doesen't recoginize that the cookies are enabled in my Browser and asks me to enable cookies.Everything works fine in Chrome and IE.

What can cause an application to suddenly start to reset itself, and It was running fine for few weeks? When I run application in VS everything seems fine and it can work for days that way.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

PS. I tried catching something useful in Global.asax under Application End,Application Error and Session End but It seems like it doesen't execute any of that?

I have experienced App restart because of error,but usually those kind of error can be catched when debugging in VS,as I said before everything is fine when I run it on my own PC in VS.

Comment: Your hosting provider made some changes to the control panel. Were there also changes in IIS config? "Auto restart" *can* be set on IIS level...

Comment: How could I take a look into ISS config, Is that publicly available to anyone or just to host provider?

Comment: If your session is not being finished and the controls loose their state something is happening with the viewstate. In any event I would have your hosting provider fix the problem, because they obviously changed something.

Comment: So you are sure it's Viewstate related? PS. I've made changes to code to automaticly start executing upon Page Load but im loosing so much data from all threads that didn't finish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this happen with one of my sites, and it turned out that the app pool in IIS had a maximum virtual memory limit that was set too low for the application.  So when we hit our virtual memory limit, the application pool restarted.  Perhaps something similar is going on here.

Comment: That was my tought,any tips where can I check what is memory limit set to, And how much is my app taking? This was my first tought because App is memory heavy, but not sure how to check it.

Comment: Is there any code that I can use in App to get max Virtual memory Limit?

Comment: depends on the version of iis but if you go to properties/advanced settings on the app pool it's under recycling under virtual memory limit.  I'm not aware of a way to check in code, but that doesn't mean it doesn't exist ^_^

Comment: Server Info
Microsoft® Windows Server® 2008 Standard without Hyper-V Service Pack 2
Start/Up Time:
Total Memory:
Available Memory:  11/30/2011 7:18:35 AM - 0:03:34:19
25759522816 bytes
5421875200 bytes

I found this,but it's server data not app data..this is only thing available trough cp to me. I guess I will heave to google some commands if they exist! Thanks